# Drag and Drop into another div and move in the div only using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dragable div, I want to be able to drag a div and drop into another div.  It should only move inside the, dropped div.

Currently I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#move").draggable();
    $("#move1").draggable();

    $('#contain').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
             // update the draggable to be only moveable inside the droppable
             ui.draggable.draggable("option", "containment", this);
        }
    });
});
```

where #contain is the div that #move and #move1 has to be placed in and moved about.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: I don't get what you mean with this *It should only move inside the, dropped div*. Do you want to have both `div` s inside a parent `div` and the draggable `div` can only be dropped on `div`s inside this parent `div`?

Comment: @felix yes..............

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`containment`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment) option:

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region. Possible string values: 'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2].

Example:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( { containment: 'parent' } );
```

---

**Update:**  Read about the [`drop`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-drop) event. It is triggered whenever you drop a draggable onto a droppable.

Say you have your droppable `#droppable`, then you can do it this way:

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
         // update the draggable to be only moveable inside the droppable
         ui.draggable.draggable("option", "containment", this);
    }
});
```

`ui.draggable` contains the element you just dropped.

Comment: I got the divs to drag, but I cannot contain it in the <div> I drag it to.

Comment: @Jean: Do you have any problems with this code? I think it should be `$('#contain').droppable({..` and it has to be `ui.draggable` instead of `ui.contain`. This is described in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: I checked the doc, and re did the code, check for revised code in the Q

I can drop #move and #move1 into #contain, but I cannot move them inside

Comment: @Jean: Yes this is how it should be like. I created a small example http://jsbin.com/iweku you can see the source code at http://jsbin.com/iweku/edit . Tell me if this is what you want, if so, you are there ;) You should state your problem in your question too.

Comment: @felix you r da man, yup thats what i want.  So what exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: @Jean: I don't know, the code you posted is the same I use (you can see it here http://jsbin.com/iweku/edit). Make sure your syntax is correct. Use Firebug for Firefox the see whether you get any Javascript errors.

Comment: @Felix, this is getting funny and strange.  I copy/paste the entire code as/is and it does not work AT ALL, no drag, no anything....

Comment: @Jean: As I said, get a tool to debug your JS. The code itself works fine, there is not much I can do from here. If you have a link to your page, I can have a look. (btw. you really accept more answers, that is probably a reason why no one else is helping).

Comment: @Jean: Oh, I missed the *should* : You really *should* accept more answers ;)

Comment: @feilx How should I accept more answers, I quite didnt get what you are trying to convey.

There is no error in the chrome->inspect->resources.

Comment: @Jean: People are more willing to help you, if you increase your "accepted answer" ratio. This way, the can see that you are "honoring" their effort to provide a good answer (the get reputation points for accepted answers). Your ratio is at 34% which is very low. And I bet there are more answers than only those you accepted that helped you...

Comment: @feilx If the solution does work, I accept the answer, and + for that answer too.